# Last child selector not working on a navigation menu

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm adding a separator "|" to every menu item using the `:after` selector. This adds it to the last element as well. I've been trying to remove that using the `:last-child` selector and it isn't working.

I'll list my code below and also provide a jsfiddle link.

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav_bar">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_bar {
    background-color: #debb23;
    height: 45px;
}

#nav_bar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav_bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#nav_bar ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

#nav_bar ul li:after{
    content: "|";
    color: #ffffff;
}

#nav_bar ul li:last-child {
    content: none;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle link, http://jsfiddle.net/e3x369k0/

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting the last li element's content not its `:after` pseudo element's content.

Change your selector from:

```
#nav_bar ul li:last-child {
    content: none;
}
```

to

```
#nav_bar ul li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5x55emaf/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `:after` in the last CSS rule. Should be like this: `#nav_bar ul li:last-child:after`

Answer (score 0):

Try This and I've been using this technique in years :)

```
#nav_bar ul li{
border-right:1px solid black;
}

#nav_bar ul li:last-child{
border-right: 1px solid tranparent;
}
```